# Convert Base64 jpg to Base64Tiff in Java

Tags: java, image, jpeg, tiff

I have a Base64 jpeg String. I want it to convert to Tiff and make the Tiff as Base64 String. I am using JAI library.

All the other answers saved the Tiff. I do not want to save the tiff into disk. I just want to take the Base64 String.

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: If you have a tiff, just encode it in Base64. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Actually the sample programs used imageio to write directly. Is there any way to make it a b64 string and not write to file directly

Comment: There should be a way to send the output to a normal `OutputStream` that you can further process with the Base64 encoder. See for example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/stream/MemoryCacheImageOutputStream.html

Comment: Here is the code I am using::

Comment: As @Henry says, just write the TIFF to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then encode the byte array to Base64. This is a general solution that will work with any format or type, not just TIFF.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to convert an image to a Base64 representation in any format can be:

```
private static String toBase64(BufferedImage image, String formatName) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024 * 1024);

    if (!ImageIO.write(image, formatName, bytes)) {
        throw new IIOException("Error writing " + formatName);
    }

    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes.toByteArray());
}
```

For your specific case, use:

```
String encoded = toBase64(image, "TIFF");
```